# How to manage the choice of colors for a product, Nodejs React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I'm a little bit stuck, I would like to know how you would manage the addition of colors for a product knowing that a color is linked to an image. Because then on the front I would like to ensure that when a user chooses a color the image of the chosen color appears.
I use NodeJs and mongodb for the back and React for the front.

According to the data schema that you will give, can you also show me how you manage the addition of a product.

Thanks

I put you small extract of my current code

```
const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, description, price, stock, categoryId } = req.body;

  try {
    let category;

    // Check if name is empty
    if (!name) {
      return res.json({ error: "Le champ nom est obligatoire" });
    }
    // Check if price is empty
    if (!price) {
      return res.json({ error: "Le champ prix est obligatoire" });
    }
    // Check if stock is empty
    if (!stock) {
      return res.json({ error: "Le champ stock est obligatoire" });
    }

    if (req.fileFilterError) {
      return res.json({ error: req.fileFilterError });
    }

    // Check if slug exist
    const exist = await Product.findOne({ slug: slugify(name) });
    if (exist) {
      return res.json({
        error: "Veuillez fournir un nom de produit différent.",
      });
    }

    if (categoryId) {
      category = await Category.findById(categoryId);
      if (!category) {
        return res.json({ error: "La catégorie n'existe pas" });
      }
    }

    const reqFiles = [];
    const url = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host");

    for (let index = 0; index < req.files.length; index++) {
      reqFiles.push(url + "/uploads/" + req.files[index].filename);
    }

    const product = await Product.create({
      name,
      description,
      price: parseFloat(price.replace(",", ".")),
      stock,
      images: reqFiles,
      category: category ? categoryId : null,
      slug: slugify(name),
    });

    res.json({ product, success: "Produit créé avec succès !" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in createProduct", error);
  }
};
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    images: { type: Array, required: true },
    stock: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
    slug: { type: String, unique: true },
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const ProductModel = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
module.exports = ProductModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `ProductSchema` to include an array of color options, each containing a color name and its associated image

```js
const ProductSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    colors: [
      {
        colorName: { type: String, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
      },
    ],
    stock: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
    slug: { type: String, unique: true },
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Then you just do this

```js
const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, description, price, stock, categoryId, colors } = req.body;
  // code
  const product = await Product.create({
      name,
      description,
      price: parseFloat(price.replace(",", ".")),
      stock,
      colors: colors.map((color) => ({
        colorName: color.colorName,
        image: reqFiles[color.imageIndex], // Assuming you send the selected image index from the frontend
      })),
      category: category ? categoryId : null,
      slug: slugify(name),
    });
   // code
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer :), but I don't understand how I could test the addition in postman, I'm a bit lost in this case I don't know what to put in the keys, knowing also that I use multer for l adding pictures